# A control-flow abstraction based on promises and observing a value

Tags: javascript, promise, observer-pattern, control-flow

I often find myself needing a a particular control-flow abstraction in JavaScript, and I'm wondering if it may already have a name and implementation. It's much like a promise, but also much like observing a value.

Basically, it would allow you to 'watch' a value or set of values, making a clear distinction between values that are `undefined` and values that are not. Leaving error handling aside for the moment, it would have two states. In the left state, the value (or one of the values in the set) is undefined. In the right state, the value (or all the values in the set) is defined.

[image: A state automaton to illustrate the control flow pattern I'm talking about. In the watched array, 'd' stands for some defined value and 'u' stands for some undefined value.]

You can register a callback for all three types of transition. If the value is already defined, this immediately triggers one of those callbacks --- like a promise. But it's also unlike a promise, because the value can change any number of times.

Example:

```
watch([value1, value2, value3])
.onDefined(function (vals) {
    /* the values are now defined */
}
.onUndefined(function () {
    /* one or more of the values is now undefined */
})
.onChange(function (vals, oldVals) {
    /* the values are defined, and one of them just changed */
});
```

(It may not be useful to distinguish between `onDefined` and `onChange`. I'm not sure.)

Does this, or something like this, already exist? I'd be happy to be referred to (JavaScript) libraries, websites, research papers, etc.

Comment: Welcome to a wonderful learning experience http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2014/Keynote-Duality https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor

Comment: The "changes it's value any number of times" thingy is a *Signal*. I'm not sure about the signal representing a set of values, though.

Comment: I don't see why observers can't get this job done :)

Comment: What exactly is triggering the transitions of the individual values? Is the set itself mutable, i.e. can you add/remove "slots" arbitrarily? Where are you using this pattern - you say you'd need it often?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks. I'll definitely have a look!

Comment: Inb4 - a value changing several time is like multiple values, it's like an async enumerable which is called an observable. Each of your values are observables so you have a set of those, the libraries you're looking for are called BaconJS and RxJS and are pretty decent.

Comment: @Bergi: A signal? I've worked with signals & slots in Qt before, but that's just an event system. The transitions are triggered by one (or more) of the watched values changing. I use this, for instance, to set up and break down certain functionality that should only work when a number of options are turned on. Or when multiple entities should be visually connected with arrows, but only when all of them are visible at the same time.

Comment: @Winchestro: Yes, it's definitely closest to the observer pattern. There are some differences, though. For instance, if a value is already defined, the callback should fire immediately when it is registered. And the clean distinction between defined and undefined seems quite valuable, especially when watching multiple values at the same time. ----- Sure, this could be implemented on top of observers. But if my more specific pattern is already being discussed by another name, I would like to know and learn more.

Comment: Afaik, the term [*Signal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_programming) is used besides Qt, and means a continuously defined value that changes discretely (and can be observed). I don't think there's a name for this pattern, it's just an `all` method lifted into that "changing values" domain, with a type like `[Signal<Option<V>>] -> Signal<Option<[V]>>`